# Remove last character from string if its length equals x

Tags: string, powershell

I have this list of items:

```
MADE2530
CYLR8719
CLMX0020E
CLMX9257E
CLMR9133
CYLX6441E
CYLX8474E
MADX3684
```

The output i need, should look like this:

```
MADE2530
CYLR8719
CLMX0020
CLMX9257
CLMR9133
CYLX6441
CYLX8474
MADX3684
```

What I have so far is this script which is supposed to remove the last character if the length equals 9:

```
(Get-Content list.txt) | ForEach-Object { 
if ($_.length -eq 9) { $_ -replace ".$" } 
} | Set-Content list.txt
```

But the output looks like this:

```
CLMX0020
CLMX9257
CYLX6441
CYLX8474
```

It removes the 8 character strings. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an `else` in there to cover the other items:

```
(Get-Content list.txt) | ForEach-Object { 
if ($_.length -eq 9) { $_ -replace ".$" } 
else {$_}
} | Set-Content list.txt
```

Comment: :) hehe i was thinking about an else, but i don't know powershell sintax so much . Thank you. It works!